# javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Client's transaction aborted

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, persistence, eclipselink

I have recently change my database, there was some change in database so I have change my code and entities accordingly, Old database exist for history record.

Application working fine with new database but whenever there is create method called application threw that exception.

When I run my old code that run fine with old database, I am confuse what i am missing when I configure it for new database ....

```
WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB CPEHardwareModelFacade, method: public void kics.green.acs.ejb.facade.CPEHardwareModelFacade.create(kics.green.acs.ejb.entity.CPEHardwareModel)
WARNING: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Client's transaction aborted
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.useClientTx(BaseContainer.java:4722)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1914)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy443.create(Unknown Source)
    at kics.green.acs.ejb.businessdelegate.ACSMessageBean.onMessage(ACSMessageBean.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor459.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4180)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5368)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1099)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:81)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:171)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy449.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:114)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)


Line with error
GreenACSEJBLookUp.lookupCPEHardwareModelFacadeLocal().create(cpeHardwareModel);
```

Answer (score 1):

The transactionRolledbackLocalException is thrown when you try to navigate to another entity (e.g. another EJB via a @Local interface) after the transaction has already been marked for rollback. It's usually the case that a unhandled exception has been thrown somewhere - the real cause of the exception can be sometimes be swallowed and difficult to determine.

My advice is to step through using the debugger...